# While running SQL commands through shell script, Column headers are getting trimmed

Tags: sql, bash, oracle, shell, unix

I'm writing a shell script to get data using multiple select queries one after another but in my result output, my column headers are getting trimmed after two characters.

Result I'm getting(Column names/headers)

| ST | COUNT1 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Instead desired result should be:

| STATUS | COUNT1 |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

I'm using these set commands on my script

```
typeset -r SQL_SET_PARA="set TERMOUT ON echo on define off pagesize 15 linesize 4000 lines 5000 heading on verify off feedback off wrap off trimspool on serveroutput on long 20000000 longchunksize 20000000  space 9"
```

also tried adding `"SET column STATUS format A6"`, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `STATUS` column data fits into 2 characters/number. The data length is 2 for this column and SQL*Plus(By Default) truncates the name of the column to the underlying data type length. Unfortunately, there is no option to get away with this behavior using any of the SQL*Plus parameters.

But you can use the column-level formatting as follows for the `STATUS` column

```
column STATUS format A6
```

Comment: I have multiple columns such as these, is there a way to format all of them in a single command.   Just in case STATUS is an alias for D_status. i tried putting the column command in the script, still no change.

Comment: You need to provide the format for each column individually

Comment: typeset -r SQL_SET_PARA="set TERMOUT ON echo on define off pagesize 15 linesize 4000 lines 5000 heading on verify off feedback off wrap off trimspool on serveroutput on long 20000000 longchunksize 20000000  space 5 column STATUS format A6"